# Using HTTP HEAD method when the underlying ressource does not allow GET

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

We have a REST API with hyperlink support. With our automated tests we can then walk through all of the links in the response and check if they are correct, i.e. actually reachable. For this we currently use the HEAD HTTP method. Now, the spec states that HEAD should essentially behave like GET, but without a body. So far so good.

But, we also have some endpoints which ONLY support DELETE or PUT, but no GET.

The question: is it still valid HTTP - or makes even sense - if we check those endpoints with HEAD as well? Of course in this case there shouldn't be any side effects, the purpose of the test essentially would only be: *"Endpoint, are you alive and reachable"?*

Any ideas (or maybe alternatives)?

Answer (score 1):

> The question: is it still valid HTTP - or makes even sense - if we check those endpoints with HEAD as well?

Yes, it makes perfect sense.

[405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) is your ally here, that gives you a way to distinguish resources that aren't readable from resources without representations (404).

The broad principal is that, in REST, all resources understand the same methods the same way.  So HEAD is always a reasonable choice to use.

That said, you might want to review [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7), which like HEAD is also [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), and is designed to allow you to inquire about which methods are supported by a given resource.

Comment: Well, what still bothers me is this sentence from the specs: "The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.". But, what to return if there is no GET method actually supported with this resource? About OPTIONS: that could be an alternative, but what about the rules if the resource is unreachable (i.e. gives a 401, 403 or 404), would I still get those status codes?